# Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, portable-class-library

I'm developing a cross platform mobile application using **Xamarin** and **Visual Studio 2013**. I'm using **Portable Class Libraries** and I'm writing my code in the **PCL** project.

Whenever I try to debug my app on the virtual android emulator I get this exception:

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.animation.ValueAnimator in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d0b930
```

How comes? What is ValueAnimator?

Comment: Is the error thrown by the IDE or your code?

Comment: it's an error by the IDE

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into a very similar issue last night when I was working with a Xamarin.Forms application in Xamarin Studio.  I had recently updated the Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 packages in my Android project when it started happening.  I believe what I did to get it to work again (I tried a number of things so I'm not exactly sure which one actually fixed it) was to go into my Android project and delete the references to both Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Android.Supoort.v4.  Then I went into "Manage NuGet Packages" and I added the official Xamarin.Forms library. Since the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 package is a dependency it pulled that down for me as well.  I cleaned and rebuilt my project and I got passed the error.